# What male characters are in Touhou?

Tags: touhou-project

Touhou Project has a lot of characters, but the vast majority of them are female. Even though Gensokyo has plenty of men, for whatever reason they are very rarely relevant to the story. To the best of my knowledge, none of the men have appeared in the games (excluding non-humanoid characters like Unzan), but they do appear in manga side-stories and other canon works.

Can someone provide a list of the major (named characters, characters with significant impact on the plot, etc.) canon male characters in Touhou Project? I'm mostly interested in human or humanoid characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, [Rinnosuke Morichika](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Rinnosuke_Morichika) is the only male character that is significant to the plot. He's the main character of the Curiosities of Lotus Asia (official) story compilation, which focuses on his life as the proprietor of [Kourindou](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Kourindou), a store that sells antiquities from the Outside World.

Reimu Hakurei, Marisa Kirisame, Youmu Konpaku, Remilia Scarlet, Yukari Yakumo, Sakuya Izayoi and many other Touhou characters are mentioned in those stories, which is why I'd say it's relevant.

You could also count [Youki Konpaku](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Youki_Konpaku) (Youmu's predecessor at Hakugyokurou) and [Marisa's father](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Marisa%27s_unnamed_father) as other important male characters, but I don't recall those characters ever being developed. They were mentioned in order to develop Youmu and Marisa's characters.

**Edit**: If you want an extensive list of male gods/human/humanoid characters and you don't care whether they're relevant or not:

- [Bishamonten](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Bishamonten): an actual god in Buddhist mythology, worshipped by [Byakuren Hijiri](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Byakuren_Hijiri)
- [The Two Gateguards of the Lunar Capital](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Gateguards_of_the_Lunar_Capital#Gateguards_of_the_Lunar_Capital)
- [Iwakasa](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Iwakasa): one of the guys who was told to dispose of the Hourai Elixir
- [Lord Tsukuyomi](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Lord_Tsukuyomi): founder of the Lunar Capital
- [Mizue no Uranoshimako](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Mizue_no_Uranoshimako)
- [Myouren Hijiri](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Myouren_Hijiri): Byakuren's brother
- [Shirou Sendai](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Shirou_Sendai): a man who brought good fortune to every business he would visit, mentioned in Wild and Horned Hermit
- [Taisui Xingjun](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Taisui_Xingjun): tried to cause a disaster to Gensokyo in a dream Hong Meiling had
- [Tenma](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Tenma): chief of the Tengu at Youkai Mountain
- [Unshou](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Unshou): a mysterious fisherman who appears in Wild and Horned Hermit

Comment: See also [Category:Males](https://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Category:Males) on the Touhou wiki.